# Repeat event in non - GregorianCalendar

Tags: android, calendar, hebrew

I tried to add events that are repeated once a year to a Hebrew calendar using a rule.
The first date was added like the correct Hebrew date, but the repeated events were added on dates according to the Gregorian calendar.

How can I repeat the event according to the Hebrew date?

(Or must I create a list of the right dates and then add them all to the calendar?
Right now I need the user to save the first event, but I want that the repeated events are be added automatically.)

```java
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
            calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title_s);
            HebrewCalendar calDate = new HebrewCalendar(5780, month, day);
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location_s);
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description_s);
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                    calDate.getTimeInMillis());
            calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                    calDate.getTimeInMillis());
            
            calIntent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY;COUNT=20")  ; //To set the repeat rule
            startActivity(calIntent);
```

Comment: Have you read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7529? the draft might be easier on the eyes to read https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-daboo-icalendar-rscale-02.html.  I suggest mocking up an ics example by hand in text editor and see how well the RRULE:RSCALE=HEBREW; is handled by the major calendar applications (google, apple etc)